# Autolayout constraint conflict when I specified just one constraint

Tags: ios, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I have the following simple test code in my controller:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *view = [UIView new];
    [self setView:view];

    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    [label setText:@"Hello World!"];

    [view addSubview:label];

    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[label]"
        options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
}
```

The code fails with the following exception and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
2013-04-15 14:15:47.880 libmarkup-test[1072:c07] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. > Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x753eb60 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UILabel:0x7536b60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x75376a0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x712a2c0 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7536b60.midX ==>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x753eb60 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UILabel:0x7536b60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x75376a0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The "unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" message is especially confusing since, as far as I can tell, I'm only specifying one constraint.

Comment: For some reason, the question was posted before I was done writing it.

Comment: Greg: where are you setting the frame for the view? and why are you using setView? do you want to add that view you're creating as a subview for some controller? I'm not sure we have enough info to help you out.

Comment: I'm not setting the view's frame - I'm setting it as the view for my controller. The controller sizes it to fill the screen. This code is being executed in loadView. I have added more context to the code sample.

Comment: Incidentally, if I comment out the call to addConstraints:options:metrics:views: and instead set the frame of the UILabel directly (e.g. [label setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 320, 20)]), the sample works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the UILabel. By default it will be YES. So the autoresizing mask on that label are translated to additional constraints, which are then conflicting with the one you specified.

Adding this should fix the constraint issue:

`label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

You should probably think about a vertical constraints on that label as well.

Comment: before and after "Will attempt to recover...", you don't see a list of constraints? You should see at least one after, and at least two before that line.

Comment: I do...looks like the editor treated that part as markup, though, so it didn't come through. I just reformatted the post so you can see it.

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem - thank you. However, it is a bit surprising. I wouldn't expect to need to set that flag to NO since I'm not explicitly setting the label's auto-resizing mask (according to the docs, the default value is UIViewAutoresizingNone). Is there any way to avoid the need to set this flag?

Comment: Perfect. So, yes, you can see the constraint that starts with `<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x712a2c0...` is the one which was conflicting with the constraint you created.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I hadn't noticed the "NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint" text before. But I'm still confused as to why it is being applied, since I haven't set the auto-resizing mask.

Comment: `UIViewAutoresizingNone` is an autoresizing mask. (it's not the absence of one). Its just the value that says "Don't resize me". That gets translated to the appropriate layout constraints unless you say otherwise. This is for compatibility with older code.

Comment: What you describe does seem consistent with what I'm observing. However, I find it very confusing that UIViewAutoresizingNone (which is defined as 0) would translate to any kind of constraints. To me, it seems like it would be more intuitive to convert a non-zero value to a constraint specification, but not a zero (or "none") value. Do you know of any way to change the default value of translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the value happens to be zero, what matters is it introduces an important and real layout constraint (fixed size, variable margins). Autolayout has to respect that contraint for views that are unaware of it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But while UIViewAutoresizingNone could translate to "fixed size, variable margins", it seems like it could just as easily be viewed as "don't include me in any kind of automatic layout". It seems like that would produce the same results, but in a less confusing manner.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28271/discussion-between-greg-brown-and-firoze-lafeer)

Comment: @greg brown, your second interpretation would break existing code, that has always expected the first interpretation. In any case, would suggest you file a bug in radr if you think the OS handles this incorrectly. The question here at SO are about how iOS actually works today.

Comment: I think I understand now. The auto-resize mask applies only to the *size* of the view, not its frame (which also includes the view's location). Specifying UIViewAutoresizingNone tells iOS to preserve the view's size but its location may still be adjusted. I was reading "auto-resize=none" as "auto-layout=none", which was incorrect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great questions, great answer!

Answer (score -1):

please adjust the constraint priority( default is 1000) and hugging priority(default is 250)

Comment: This question was already correctly answered. The problem was the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag. It had nothing to do with content priorities.